# In SQL Server, how to find the database name when I know only a function name

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I know only the function name. I don't know the database name where the function is been created and present.

I have around 30 databases so it takes more time to run the function on all the databases to find the database. is there any simple way to get the database name using only function name.

i'm using SQL server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sp_msforeachdb 'select ''?'' where object_id(''myfunction'') is not null'`? I'm assuming that name is not also reused elsewhere as another object type.

Comment: the above query is not working

Comment: in SSMS, Use Object Explorer Details to search for the function over all databases.

Comment: My bad, `sp_msforeachdb` apparently does not change the database context. You have to explicitly qualify objects. `sp_msforeachdb 'IF OBJECT_ID(''[?].dbo.myfunction'') IS NOT NULL SELECT ''?'''` then.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly Jeroen's code didn't work on my SQL 2014 server. Try the following.

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 
'if exists(select 1 from [?].sys.objects where name=''YourProcHere'')
select ''?'' as DbName from [?].sys.objects where name=''YourProcHere'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this works as well:

```
sp_msforeachdb 'USE ? select ''?'' DBNAME where object_id(N''YOUR_FUNCTION'') is not null'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jeroen Mostert, Below SQL works for me:

```
sp_msforeachdb 'IF OBJECT_ID(''[?].dbo.myfunction'') IS NOT NULL SELECT ''?'''
```